# How to compile and install pysqlcipher for python 2.7 on Windows 7

Tags: python, windows, python-2.7

I have recently installed Python 2.7 on Windows 7. I have also installed setuptools and pip for python, MinGW, [Visual C++ for Python](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266), and OpenSSL over the course of my trials. All have entries in my %PATH% and I have the environment variables VS90COMNTOOLS and VS100COMNTOOLS pointing to "C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Common\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\bin".

I have tried several different ways to install this. I will outline each below. (all of there were run from an elevated command prompt.)

1. Download source and compile.

   python setup.py install

This gives the output:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pysqlcipher._sqlite' extension
error: Unable to find vcvarsall.bat
```

2. Compile source using MinGW

Since after installing VS for Python I still got the same error, I decided to try:

```
setup.py install build --compiler=mingw32
```

Output:

```
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_ext
building 'pysqlcipher._sqlite' extension
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/module.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\module.o
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/connection.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\connection.o
src/connection.c: In function '_pysqlite_final_callback':
src/connection.c:787:15: warning: variable 'aggregate_class' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     PyObject* aggregate_class;
               ^
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/cursor.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\cursor.o
src/cursor.c: In function 'pysqlite_cursor_dealloc':
src/cursor.c:129:9: warning: variable 'rc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int rc;
         ^
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/cache.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\cache.o
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/microprotocols.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\microprotocols.o
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/prepare_protocol.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\prepare_protocol.o

D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/statement.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\statement.o
src/statement.c: In function 'pysqlite_statement_dealloc':
src/statement.c:408:9: warning: variable 'rc' set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
     int rc;
         ^
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/util.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\util.o
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c src/row.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\src\row.o
D:\Developer\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -mdll -O -Wall -DMODULE_NAME=\"pysqlcipher.dbapi2\" -DSQLITE_ENABLE_FTS3=1 -DSQLITE_ENABL
E_RTREE=1 -DSQLITE_ENABLE_LOAD_EXTENSION=1 -DSQLITE_HAS_CODEC=1 -DSQLITE_TEMP_STORE=2 -Iamalgamation -ID:\Developer\Pyth
on27\include -ID:\Developer\Python27\PC -c amalgamation\sqlite3.c -o build\temp.win32-2.7\Release\amalgamation\sqlite3.o

amalgamation\sqlite3.c:13654:26: fatal error: openssl/rand.h: No such file or directory
 #include <openssl/rand.h>
                          ^
compilation terminated.
error: command 'D:\\Developer\\MinGW\\bin\\gcc.exe' failed with exit status 1
```

3. I installed OpenSSL and tried again. Still the same output. I also installed pyopenssl. Still the same error.
4. I tried going the easy way:

   easy_install pysqlcipher

   pip install pysqlcipher

These also complain about not being able to find 'openssl/rand.h'

Does anyone have any ideas how to resolve this so I can compile this package for Windows?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Method 1

Install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

Update pip

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

Update setuptools

```
pip install -U setuptools
```

Use pip to install pysqlcipher

```
pip install pysqlcipher
```

`pip` should be able to find your install of the Visual C++ Compiler, and compile the needed extensions.

If for some reason you can't use pip, then try method 2 below.

---

### Method 2

Look in your `setup.py` If it is an older package it may be importing `distutils.core.setup()` rather than `setuptools.setup()`.

I ran in to this (in 2015) with a combination of these factors:

1. The Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7 from http://aka.ms/vcpython27
2. An older package that uses `distutils.core.setup()`
3. Trying to do `python setup.py build` rather than using `pip`.

If you use a recent version of pip, it will force (monkeypatch) the package to use setuptools, even if its `setup.py` calls for distutils. However, if you are not using pip, and instead are just doing `python setup.py build`, the build process will use `distutils.core.setup()`, which does not know about the compiler install location.

**Step 1:** Install the [Microsoft Visual C++ Compiler for Python 2.7](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44266)

**Step 2:** Open the appropriate Visual C++ 2008 Command Prompt

Open the Start menu or Start screen, and search for "Visual C++ 2008 32-bit Command Prompt" (if your python is 32-bit) or "Visual C++ 2008 64-bit Command Prompt" (if your python is 64-bit). Run it. The command prompt should say Visual C++ 2008 ... in the title bar.

**Step 3:** Set environment variables

Set these environment variables in the command prompt you just opened.

```
SET DISTUTILS_USE_SDK=1
SET MSSdk=1
```

Reference http://bugs.python.org/issue23246

**Step 4:** Build and install

`cd` to the package you want to build, and run `python setup.py build`, then `python setup.py install`. If you want to install in to a virtualenv, activate it before you build.

Answer (score 1):

This is most common issue, I have faced. But I used [pytools for Visual Studio 2012](http://pytools.codeplex.com/) to solve this. After installing pytools a new project category is added in New Project [image]

Select your python project. Add python environment from your project Solution Explorer, right click on it and select "Add / Remove Python Environment...". A window will appear with check box option, select your current python version (installed in your system).

[image]

An environment will be added like (Here Python 2.7). Again right click on it and select "Install Python Package" option.
[image]

A window is rise with pip and easy_install option. Now just type your package name eg. pyopenssl. Check run as administrator. Click ok button

[image]

[image]

Console output determines is your package installed perfectly or not.

I hope this'll help you.

Comment: I already have pyopenssl installed. The package that I am trying to install is pysqlcipher. Thanks!

Comment: Actually I tried VS 12 to install packages. I think if you write pysqlcipher in "Install Python Package" text field and you also may select easy_install option from pip dropdown list.